# How to change default width to <table> html in CDATA using BIRT

Tags: html, birt, cdata

I have a rptdesign for multiple variable reports using cdata tag.
I have to program a new one report that includes a table html.
I have gotten bgcolor, border, alignment ......but I am not able to change width cells.
My browser render ok my html code how ever birt does not recognise width attributes.
I am using inline html attributes on it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please update the question with your code. At best a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have add HTML code.